# How should I fix an illegal declaration in winnt.h in order to avoid disabling the project's quality checks?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

The project build complains about an anonymous struct when trying to build without the language extensions enabled. Is there a way to fix this?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\winnt.h(12366): error C2467: illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'
```

Comment: ... what is your code?

Comment: Solution: Either `1` blame the developers, or `2` go learn C++ and fix it yourself.

Comment: There is no way to build the Windows librarys without language extensions. Those extensions were pretty much invented for Microsoft to use themselves.

Comment: Why don't you enable language extensions?

Comment: @ZanLynx they are trying to make the windows SDK clean of extensions but they have to be very very careful because of compatibility with old code. AFAIK they want to be able to compile with latest C++, W4, and `/permissive-` without any warning pops

Comment: Not sure why so much downvoting. This is a valid question and the code is widely available for free, and this is a well-known issue with microsoft headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do here is to isolate the Windows specific, actually, all of the OS specific code into its own code files. Those files will have to include the Windows headers and build with the extensions turned on.

All of your other source files can be compiled without the extensions.

The other benefit this will have is if you want to do a Linux or Mac port you just need to replace your OS implementation files.

Comment: I believe I won't be able to do this as my smart pointers make use of InterlockedIncrement() and InterlockedDecrement() and I don't know how to get rid of those. I was able to isolate the #include line to a single .h so at least I've made some progress.

Comment: Maybe I should just wrap them but I didn't want to do that because it's a performance-sensitive task so I'm currently doing it with macros.

Comment: @PabloAriel: You could stop using InterlockedIncrement and use C++11's std::atomic instead.